# Is the following algebraic structure a field?

Tags: field-theory

Is this a field?
\begin{array}{l}{(M,+, \cdot) \text { with } M=\{m+n \sqrt{5}: m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\} \text { and }+\text { and } \cdot \text { is the usual addition and}} \\ {\text { multiplication of numbers in } \mathbb{R}. }\end{array}

I found out, that the inverse element of $(M,\cdot)$ for $a$ is $a^{-1}=\frac{1}{m+n\sqrt{5}}$ but that is not in $M$, because there are no numbers $n,m$ to get $\frac{1}{m+n\sqrt{5}}$, right? (It wouldn't be a field then.)

Comment: Much simpler, $1/2 \notin M$, so $2$ has no inverse. This shows that $M$ is not a field.

Comment: Note that if $m,n\in\mathbb Q$, rather $\mathbb Z$, then $M$ would in fact be a field, known as $\mathbb Q(\sqrt5)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do the problem.

$M$ is contained in the field $\mathbb R$. The inverse to $n + m \sqrt 5$ in $\mathbb R$ has the form $a + b \sqrt 5$ for some rational numbers $a,b \in \mathbb R$. Compute these numbers and see $a$ and $b$ are not integers.

Now suppose $n + m \sqrt 5$ has an inverse $n' + m' \sqrt 5$ in $M$. Then it is also  an inverse in $\mathbb R$. Since inverses in a field are unique we have $n' + m' \sqrt 5 = a + b \sqrt 5$.

**Exercise:** Suppose $a,b,c,d$ are rational and $a + b \sqrt 5 = c + d \sqrt 5$. Prove $a=c$ and $b=d$.

The above implies $n'=a$ and $m'=b$. This contradicts how $n',m'$ are integers and $a,b$ are not. We conclude there is no inverse in $M$.

**Edit:** Of course Robert's answer proves $M$ is not a field with much less work. The above shows something much stronger. Namely that $1,-1$ are the ONLY invertible elements of $M$.

Comment: Thank you, and sry that I didn't respond.

Comment: I'm not really sure how I should prove it formally, but it's because $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational and $a,b,c,d$ are rational. We won't find $a,b,c,d$ with $a\neq c, b\neq d$ to satisfy $a+b\sqrt 5 = c+d\sqrt 5$. Well, I just reflected what you already said, I can't really tell how to prove it in a good way.

Comment: Hint: Assume such $a,b,c,d$ exist and manipulate the equation to reach a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Existence of inverse for non-zero elements is required for $M$ to be a field, so you are correct.

For a counter-example it's usually more clear to pick one counter-example (e.g. $2\in M$ but $\frac{1}{2}\notin M$), but your reasoning is correct.

Comment: why the -1 on the question and answers?

Comment: I'm not really sure, maybe someone had a bad day.

Comment: @Robert Chamberlain I don't know the answer to your question (at the moment the -1s have changed to a 0 and +1s anyway), but for the OP's reasoning to be complete, I believe he or she needs to note also at least that there are integers $\ m\ $ and $\ n\ $ for which $\ \frac{m}{m^2-5n^2}\ $ and $\ \frac{n}{m^2-5n^2}\ $ are not both also integers.